# How to track user activity and visits inTableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, user-tracking

1. I have 7 tableau dashboard which is used by 200 user in different location
2. There is no authentication/ login page for these dashboard
3. User of these dashboard are using Chrome and IE browser

**My requirement is that :**

1. I need to track number of visits for these dashboard
2. Manager wants to track what are the user's who have visited this site, in order to increase the adherence
3. How to connect this with LDAP or custom authentication mechanism?

Does Tableau has in built component for this if not what is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Tableau Server Admins can do this with built-in functionality. Please see the Server admin docs. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_analyze_sample_workbook.htm

Also, tableau allows access to its internal postgres db, which tracks all activity. Admins can create customized dashboards for further tracking needs outside of the canned reports available. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/data_dictionary.html